# Why do quantum memories have to be so cold?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, crystals

I understand that currently, atomic qubits, or just atomic ensembles are kept near absolute zero, in order to try to create an ideal gas structure. For higher temperatures the individual ions will move, and phonons will be transferring energy, and so it makes sense to try to isolate the rare-earth ions from it's surrounding crystal, at least for now.

However, is it possible to account for these interferences from the crystal? Is it possible to build a functional quantum computer at temperatures above absolute zero?

Comment: Cold gases deviate significantly from an ideal gas, and anyway the temperature of a single isolated ion isn't well defined, so I'm not quite sure what you're asking about. You seem to be referring to trapped-ion qubits 
(as opposed to superconducting qubits or nitrogen-vacancy qubits), which are neither part of a crystal nor part of a gas; they're isolated from everything, including each other, except for explicit manipulation by the experimenter.

Comment: if you don't get a satisfactory answer here you might try to ask this question on [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com), as it is of direct relevance with QCs